# Sum of generic arrays missing type constraint

Tags: generics, f#

I'm trying to write a simple array add function. The only complexity comes from my attempt at making it generic. I know that in C# there's no type constraint for a value type, but my understanding is that F# can make it work with an [explicit member constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Here's my attempt:

```
let Add<'T when 'T : (member (+) : 'T -> 'T -> 'T)> (A : 'T[]) (B : 'T[]) =
    Array.init A.Length (fun i -> A.[i] + B.[i])
```

the compiler lists three errors: one on A.[i], one on the + sign, one on B.[i], but my guess is that they're all the same:

```
A type parameter is missing a constraint 
'when  ^T : (static member ( + ) :  ^T *  ^T ->  ^?6069)'
```

I'm sure this is just a syntax problem, can anyone point me in the right place?

p.s.: is there a different / easier way to do this, or is this the right way to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark the function `inline`. The constraint will then be inferred.

```
let inline Add (A : 'T[]) (B : 'T[]) =
  Array.init A.Length (fun i -> A.[i] + B.[i])
```

Your function could also be written this way:

```
let inline add a b = Array.map2 (+) a b
```

EDIT

To make the constraint explicit you can do this (which looks awful)

```
let inline Add< ^T when ^T : (static member (+) : ^T * ^T -> ^T) > (A : ^T[]) (B : ^T[]) =
    Array.init A.Length (fun i -> (^T : (static member (+) : ^T * ^T -> ^T) (A.[i], B.[i])))
```

but it generates the warning:

> Member constraints with the name 'op_Addition' are given special status by the F# compiler as certain .NET types are implicitly augmented with this member. This may result in runtime failures if you attempt to invoke the member constraint from your own code.

Comment: fantastic! any idea why the compiler is not happy with my version?

Comment: Yes. Explicit member constraints require `inline`.

Comment: I'm getting the same errors whether I declare the function `inline` or not

Comment: Your syntax was off a bit. However, a constraint on `(+)` has special meaning to the compiler and generates a warning.

Comment: Awful is an understatement. Thanks!